# SSHd of Linux Server keeps on getting failed and recovered every few hours

Tags: ssh-keys, sshd, cpanel, linux-server, digital-ocean

I am using Digital Ocean's Droplet Linux server, with Cpanel. It was all ok but now we are receiving continuous mails every 2 hours from Cpanel with title, "[Hostname] FAILED ⛔: sshd (Server IP Address)" and after five minutes another mail with title "[Hostname] RECOVERED ❇: sshd (Server IP Address)". I thought it was due to SSL Certificate Expiry, so I renewed it. You can check those mails in links below.

SSHd Failed Mail Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D08aT.png

SSHd Recovered Mail Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLrZL.png

I contacted Digital Ocean but they said they can't help me, as droplet is self managed by user. I also contacted Cpanel, they gave me following findings from SSHd logs -

```
Feb 15 18:19:35 s1.praczo.com sshd[8785]: bad permissions: ignore key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Feb 15 18:19:35 s1.praczo.com sshd[8785]: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Feb 15 18:19:52 s1.praczo.com sshd[8802]: error: Permissions 0640 for '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key' are too open.
Feb 15 18:19:52 s1.praczo.com sshd[8802]: error: It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
Feb 15 18:19:52 s1.praczo.com sshd[8802]: error: This private key will be ignored.
```

Based off the above errors, Cpanel told me to make sure that the `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` ​has proper permissions set.

Also, sent me one more error log -

```
Feb 15 18:19:35 s1.praczo.com sshd[8785]: error: Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.
```

I tried many things from google but problem is not solved. I don't have any System Administrator to solve this issue. So had to ask here. What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The "sshd service appears to be down" could be the service crashing. Check if everything is up to date, look if there are any signs of an attack via Internet (hundreds of connection attempts might bring it down, ssh is a common target for all sorts of miscreants).